# Date wise data retrieval from SQL Server to Excel using VB.NET form

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, vb.net, export-to-excel

I want to create a reporting software in which date is retrieved on the date specified by the user through datepicker tool in user form. I want to know how to implement the code in order to get the result.

This is my code... Please help me. I'm new to this

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1
    Private conn As New SqlConnection
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Try
            conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=ROG\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=GKEAPL;Integrated Security=True;"
            conn.Open()
            MsgBox("Connected")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Could Not connect")
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Try
            Dim officeexcel As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
            officeexcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
            Dim workbook As Object = officeexcel.Workbooks.Add("D:\GKEAPL\project 1\gk format.xltx")
            officeexcel.Visible = True
            Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
            Dim ds As New DataSet
            da = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT FeedWaterTankLevelFWST101,
                                    FeedFlowFT101,
                                    ClearWaterTankLevelCWST201,
                                    TMFilPressurePT201,
                                    TMFolPressurePT202,
                                    HPPilPressurePT203,
                                    MembraneilPressurePT204,
                                    MembraneolPressurePT205,
                                    PermeateFlowFT201,
                                    RejectFlowFT202
                 FROM DATA1 WHERE(DATEnTIME >='2020-12-18 11:06:30.000' AND DATEnTIME <= '2020-12-19 10:07:31.000')", conn)
            da.Fill(ds, "DATA1")

            For i As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables("DATA1").Rows.Count - 1

                With officeexcel
                    .Range("Sheet2!B" + (i + 7).ToString).Value = ds.Tables("DATA1").Rows(i).Item(0).ToString
                    .Range("Sheet2!C" + (i + 7).ToString).Value = ds.Tables("DATA1").Rows(i).Item(1).ToString
                    .Range("Sheet2!D" + (i + 7).ToString).Value = ds.Tables("DATA1").Rows(i).Item(2).ToString
                    .Range("Sheet2!E" + (i + 7).ToString).Value = ds.Tables("DATA1").Rows(i).Item(3).ToString
                    .Range("Sheet1!F" + (i + 7).ToString).Value = ds.Tables("DATA1").Rows(i).Item(4).ToString
                    .Range("Sheet1!G" + (i + 7).ToString).Value = ds.Tables("DATA1").Rows(i).Item(5).ToString
                    .Range("Sheet1!H" + (i + 7).ToString).Value = ds.Tables("DATA1").Rows(i).Item(6).ToString
                    .Range("Sheet1!I" + (i + 7).ToString).Value = ds.Tables("DATA1").Rows(i).Item(7).ToString
                    .Range("Sheet1!J" + (i + 7).ToString).Value = ds.Tables("DATA1").Rows(i).Item(8).ToString
                    .Range("Sheet1!K" + (i + 7).ToString).Value = ds.Tables("DATA1").Rows(i).Item(9).ToString
                End With
            Next

            officeexcel = Nothing
            workbook = Nothing
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    End Sub
    Private Sub Report_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "YYYY-MMMM-DD"
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: What is the problem? Did you get an error?  Where and what? If it simply didn't perform as expected explain how.

Comment: Connections must be closed and disposed so they should only be created in the methods where they are used.

Comment: Do not write empty Catch blocks. They only swallow errors.

Comment: You never use the extra functionality provided by a DataAdapter and a DataSet. Just use a Command and a DataTable.

Comment: @Mary actually, I don't know how to implement the date time picker. I did get output when I put the date directly in query and but while putting variable instead of date, I am not getting output on excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not open a connection in `Form.Load`. Connections are precious resources. Keep them local to the method where they are used. Open just before the `.Execute...` line and close as soon as possible.

If you look at the `SQLConnection` class in MS docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1  you will see a `.Dispose` method. When you see that, it means it should be called to release unmanaged resources used by the class. Luckily, vb.net provides `Using...End Using` blocks to handle this for us.

I moved your data access code to a separate function. As much as possible a method should only be doing one thing.

In your sql string WHERE clause I changed your literals to parameters and used BETWEEN.

I think you have problems with the Excel code too but your question was about data access. Briefly, don't Dim workbook as Object, Range is not a member of `Excel.Application` and **turn On Option Strict now and always**.

```vb
Private Function GetTankData() As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim strSql = "SELECT FeedWaterTankLevelFWST101,
                                FeedFlowFT101,
                                ClearWaterTankLevelCWST201,
                                TMFilPressurePT201,
                                TMFolPressurePT202,
                                HPPilPressurePT203,
                                MembraneilPressurePT204,
                                MembraneolPressurePT205,
                                PermeateFlowFT201,
                                RejectFlowFT202
             FROM DATA1 WHERE DATEnTIME BETWEEN @StartDate AND  @EndDate"
    Using conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=ROG\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=GKEAPL;Integrated Security=True;"),
            cmd As New SqlCommand(strSql, conn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@StartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTimePicker1.Value
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@EndDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTimePicker2.Value
        conn.Open()
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using 'Closes and disposes the connection and command
    Return dt
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim officeexcel As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    officeexcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Dim workbook As Object = officeexcel.Workbooks.Add("D:\GKEAPL\project 1\gk format.xltx")
    Try
        officeexcel.Visible = True
        Dim dt = GetTankData()

        For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1

            With officeexcel
                .Range("Sheet2!B" + (i + 7).ToString).Value = dt.Rows(i).Item(0).ToString
                .Range("Sheet2!C" + (i + 7).ToString).Value = dt.Rows(i).Item(1).ToString
                .Range("Sheet2!D" + (i + 7).ToString).Value = dt.Rows(i).Item(2).ToString
                .Range("Sheet2!E" + (i + 7).ToString).Value = dt.Rows(i).Item(3).ToString
                .Range("Sheet1!F" + (i + 7).ToString).Value = dt.Rows(i).Item(4).ToString
                .Range("Sheet1!G" + (i + 7).ToString).Value = dt.Rows(i).Item(5).ToString
                .Range("Sheet1!H" + (i + 7).ToString).Value = dt.Rows(i).Item(6).ToString
                .Range("Sheet1!I" + (i + 7).ToString).Value = dt.Rows(i).Item(7).ToString
                .Range("Sheet1!J" + (i + 7).ToString).Value = dt.Rows(i).Item(8).ToString
                .Range("Sheet1!K" + (i + 7).ToString).Value = dt.Rows(i).Item(9).ToString
            End With
        Next
    Finally
        officeexcel = Nothing
        workbook = Nothing

    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for  your valuable response. excel part is running fine. it will be very useful and kind of you, if you post the entire code with the changes u suggested as i am a beginer and i am facing lot of issues while making the changes that u suggested. looking forward for positive reply. Thanks in advance

Comment: @AnkithKarthik I have altered your button code to include the GetTankData method. I did not change the Excel code but it doesn't look right to me.